# Getting Hidden Field Values in mvc @Html.TextBox

Tags: hiddenfield, html.textbox

I am using a autocomplete option for a textbox in asp.net mvc3 by calling a controller method to display list of values associated with ids in textbox.

```
      @Html.TextBox("tbxSearch", null,
 new { data_url = Url.Action("GetSearchData"), data_maxValues = 10, data_valueHiddenId = "#Id", @class = "searchTextbox" })
```

Now I want to use Jquery to get data_valueHiddenId value in alert

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ConfigureAutoComplete("#tbxSearch");
    $("#btnSearchPerson").click(function () {
        alert($("#data_valueHiddenId").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`data-maxValues` is an *attribute*, not an element.

You can write `$('#tbxSearch').data('maxValues')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ConfigureAutoComplete("#tbxSearch");
    $("#btnSearchPerson").click(function () {
        alert($($(this).attr("data_valueHiddenId")).val());
    });
});
```